# increase or decrease according to status with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How can I reach the 'Counter' column with pandas: If status A -> count up by one. if status B or C -> reduce by one.

| Index | Status | Counter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 2 | A | 2 |
| 3 | A | 3 |
| 4 | B | 2 |
| 5 | C | 1 |
| 6 | A | 2 |
| 7 | B | 1 |
| 8 | A | 2 |
| 9 | A | 3 |
| 10 | B | 2 |

Comment: Thank you for sharing your question with us. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the values to 1/-1 with  `numpy.where`, then perform a `cumsum`:

```
import numpy as np

df['Counter'] = (np.where(df['Status'].eq('A'), 1, -1)
                   .cumsum()
                 )
```

Output:

```
   Index Status  Counter
0      1      A        1
1      2      A        2
2      3      A        3
3      4      B        2
4      5      C        1
5      6      A        2
6      7      B        1
7      8      A        2
8      9      A        3
9     10      B        2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a loop over the dataframe's rows. You can achieve this by using `iterrows` on the dataframe:

```py
count = 0
CounterList = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
  if row["Status"] == "A":
    count += 1
  elif row["Status"] == "B" or row["Status"] == "C":
    count -= 1
  CounterList.append(count)
df["Counter"] = CounterList
df
```

##### Output

|  | Index | Status | Counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | A | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | A | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | B | 2 |
| 4 | 5 | C | 1 |
| 5 | 6 | A | 2 |
| 6 | 7 | B | 1 |
| 7 | 8 | A | 2 |
| 8 | 9 | A | 3 |
| 9 | 10 | B | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'status':['A', 'A', 'B', 'A']})
temp = df['status']=='A'
df['counter'] = temp.replace(False, -1).astype(int).cumsum()
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]