# Form subgroups and increase/decrease according to value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

My intial Dataframe looks as follows (except column `Counter`):

| Index | User | Status | Counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | A | 1 |
| 2 | Ellen | A | 1 |
| 3 | John | B | 0 |
| 4 | Ellen | A | 2 |
| 5 | John | A | 1 |
| 6 | John | A | 2 |
| 7 | John | A | 3 |
| 8 | John | A | 4 |
| 9 | Ellen | A | 3 |
| 10 | John | B | 3 |
| 11 | Ellen | B | 2 |
| 12 | Ellen | C | 1 |
| 13 | Ellen | A | 2 |
| 14 | Ellen | A | 3 |

In this case I have two users (`John/Ellen`). In fact, there are way more users.

The `Counter` column is my goal to achieve. If I had only one user, the code would look like this:

```
count = 0
CounterList = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
  if row["Status"] == "A":
    count += 1
  elif row["Status"] == "B" or row["Status"] == "C":
    count -= 1
  CounterList.append(count)
df["Counter"] = CounterList
df
```

With status A it counts up by 1, with status B or C the counter is reduced by one.

But how to handle two or more users? How to build subgroups and counting each user-subgroup separately?

Comment: This is quite similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71275454/increase-or-decrease-according-to-status-with-pandas). Is this for an assigment?

Answer (score 1):

Create a mapping from Status to its corresponding score; then `groupby` + `cumsum`:

```
mapping = {'A':1, 'B':-1,'C':-1}        
df['Counter'] = df.assign(Counter=df['Status'].map(mapping)).groupby('User')['Counter'].cumsum()
```

Output:

```
    Index   User Status  Counter
0       1   John      A        1
1       2  Ellen      A        1
2       3   John      B        0
3       4  Ellen      A        2
4       5   John      A        1
5       6   John      A        2
6       7   John      A        3
7       8   John      A        4
8       9  Ellen      A        3
9      10   John      B        3
10     11  Ellen      B        2
11     12  Ellen      C        1
12     13  Ellen      A        2
13     14  Ellen      A        3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the Status is equal to A and map 1, -1 otherwise. Then perform a cumsum per group:

```
df['Counter'] = (df['Status']
                 .eq('A').map({True: 1, False: -1}) # make A: 1, other: -1
                 .groupby(df['User']).cumsum()      # cumsum per group
                 )
```

output:

```
    Index   User Status  Counter
0       1   John      A        1
1       2  Ellen      A        1
2       3   John      B        0
3       4  Ellen      A        2
4       5   John      A        1
5       6   John      A        2
6       7   John      A        3
7       8   John      A        4
8       9  Ellen      A        3
9      10   John      B        3
10     11  Ellen      B        2
11     12  Ellen      C        1
12     13  Ellen      A        2
13     14  Ellen      A        3
```

Comment: we got similar answers; yours is very concise though; `eq` + `map` is very nice +1

Comment: @enke an alternative would be `np.where(df['Status'].eq('A'), 1, -1)` but to use groupby one would need to make it a Series first. (I answered a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71275454/increase-or-decrease-according-to-status-with-pandas) 2 days ago) ;)

Comment: @enke also I saw you used `assign`, you can use `series1.groupby(series2)` instead to make the code more concise, it will align on the index to form the groups ;)